# MySQL Counting Inquiry

Tags: mysql, sql, counting

whilst I'm still trying to figure this one out I'd like to see your feedback on my code and if you could help me. I'm still trying to grasp the concept of MySQL so any help is much appreciated! **I'm running MySQL as an HR**

The question requirement is as follows:

> Write SQL statement that return the number of employees in every
> department whose salary is more than 6000. Do not return the
> department where the average salary is more than 9000

Below is my code (It doesn't work)

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, 
       SALARY, 
       COUNT(*) 
FROM EMPLOYEES 
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE salary BETWEEN 6000 AND 9000;
```

My error message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
https://gyazo.com/2300fbf0b0ebb43294d599cee276e235 <-- Expected output

Thanks!

Comment: Please define `It doesn't work` ? Add sample data and expected result in text format

Comment: The code that I provided is my own and it has syntax errors.
The expected result is a table, I don't think I can put it here.
I have included a screenshot link to it.

Comment: If your query has syntax errors you should edit the question and add the full error. `The expected result is a table, I don't think I can put it here` yes you can. You have included the expected result but what about the data which produce the expected result? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update the question. And you should read https://stackoverflow.com/tour ,too

Comment: The data is a library generated by default by SQLQuery when editing as an HR.
When I type ```SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES;``` I get this https://gyazo.com/485f31a08790da92c0c25ff2e4c3f404

Comment: The query in your question has 2 errors. First, `GROUP BY` needs to come after `WHERE`, [per MySQL syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html). Second, `GROUP BY DEPARMENT_ID` is fine when you have `DEPARTMENT_ID` (because this is the unique value you're grouping on) and `COUNT(*)` (because this is a grouping function), but MySQL doesn't know what to do with `SALARY`. You'll need [an aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) on that column too, such as `AVG(SALARY)` in order to return aggregated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Write SQL statement that return the number of employees in every
> department whose salary is more than 6000. Do not return the
> department where the average salary is more than 9000
>
> number of employees in every department --- count(EMPLOYEE_ID)
>
> salary
> is more than 6000 --- WHERE SALARY >6000
>
> Do not return the
> department where the average salary is more than 9000 ---avg(salary)
> <=9000

This would be done by:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID,
       COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) as nr_count
FROM   EMPLOYEES 
WHERE SALARY > 6000
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID
HAVING AVG(SALARY) <=9000;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6165323c01f188bb0dbb8e6227bac7bc

Comment: Perfect! I have noticed where I have been messing up thanks a lot for your help ^_^